# Flipping the text labelled on an arrow and reducing arrow size?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, diagrams

Consider the MWE by Zarko:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 11mm and 33mm,
     N/.style = {draw, minimum size=12mm, inner sep=0pt},
            > = {Stealth[scale=0.6]},
 every edge/.append style = {draw, ->},
every edge quotes/.append style = {font=\small\linespread{0.75}\selectfont,
                                   inner sep=5pt, sloped}
                        ]
\node [N] (A) {$S$};
\node [N,above right=of A] (B) {$I_1$};
\node [N,below right=of A] (C) {$I_2$};
\node [N,above right=of C] (D) {$J$};
\node [N,right=of D] (E)  {$A$};
%
\draw [<-] (A) -- ++(-1,0) node[left] {$\mu$};
\draw [->] (A) -- ++(0,-1) node[below] {$\nu S$};
\draw [->] ([xshift=3.75mm] B.south) -- ++(0,-0.4) node[below] {$\nu I_1$};
\draw [->] (C) -- ++(0,-1) node[below] {$\nu I_2$};
\draw [->] (D) -- ++(0,-1) node[below] {$\nu J$};
\draw [->] ([xshift=-3.5mm] E.south) -- ++(0,-0.4) node[below] {$\nu \alpha$};
\draw [->] ([xshift=+3.5mm] E.south) -- ++(0,-0.4) node[below] {$\nu A$};
%
\draw   ([yshift=+1mm] A.east)
            edge [ultra thick, draw=gray,"\slash\slash\slash" anchor=center,
                  "$\begin{gathered}
                        p\beta_1 S I_1\\
                        q\beta_2 S J\\
                        r\beta_3 S A
                    \end{gathered}$"] (B.west)
        ([yshift=-1mm] A.east)
            edge [ultra thick, draw=gray,"\slash\slash\slash" anchor=center,
                  "$\begin{gathered}
                        (1-p)\beta_2 S I_1\\
                        (1-q)\beta_2 S J\\
                        (1-r)\beta_3 S A
                    \end{gathered}$" '] (C.west)
        (B) edge ["$\epsilon I_1$"] (C)
        (D.west) edge ["$\xi_1 J$"  ] ( B.east)
        ( C.east) edge ["$p_1 I_2$"  ] (D.west)
        ([yshift=-2mm] D.west) edge ["$\xi_2 J$" '] ([yshift=-2mm] C.east)
    (D) edge ["$p_2 J$"] (E);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

This is nice from Zarko, however I want to flip the $\epsilon$ so its reads "straight". I also want to shorten the arrow space from node J to A but keep everything else the same spacing, how can I achieve this?

Comment: I assume, you want to rotate the `$\epsilon$`, which you can do like this: `(B) edge [rotate=90,"$\epsilon I_1$"] (C)` (that is, just add `rotate=90,` before the label text). As for shortening the arrows, maybe you want to add the option `shorten > = 5pt,` to the set of options defined with `\begin{tikzpicture}`? I don't fully understand what you mean here.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I only want to shorten the last arrow; from J to A, it is too long hence making it overshoot my margins. The rotate solved my $\epsilon$ issue so thank you.

Comment: You can use the option `shorten > = 5pt` also with individual `\draw` commands, such like `\draw [->, shorten > = 5pt] (D) -- ++(0,-1) node[below] {$\nu J$};`. And, of course, you can use a different value than `5pt`.